# Does the final keyword provide optimization if all derived classes are known at compile time?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, compilation, final

In theory, using the `final` keyword on a virtual method declaration in C++11 and onwards allows inlining of the method.

[This can be seen here.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/0EvFW1)

However, I suspect that in practice, if it is known at compile time that there are no derived classes overriding that method, the compiler can insert a `final` for us and inline the method.

[However, putting this into compiler explorer shows that it still provides optimizations.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MZjxeJ)

Why is this?

Comment: *"if it is known at compile time that there are no derived classes"*. How do you know that?

Comment: I can read the code and see that there aren't any derived classes.

Comment: So could only be done at link, supposing  no dynamic loading...

Comment: Ah, that's the bit I was missing. So if I use link-time optimization the compiler might be able to mark a method as `final` automatically. If you could add the bit about only knowing which derived types are available at link time to your answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> final keyword on a virtual method declaration in C++11 and onwards allows inlining of the method

Not `inlining`, but de-virtualization.

> However, I suspect that in practice, if it is known at compile time that there are no derived classes overriding that method, [..]

You cannot know at compile time that there are no other derived classes (unless class is `final`): user or other TU might provide some. it might potentially be done at link, supposing no dynamic loading...

> [..] the compiler can insert a final for us and inline the method
>   However, putting this into compiler explorer shows that it still provides optimizations.
>
> ```
>  struct A {
>      virtual void f() {}
>  };
>
> struct B : public A {
>      void f() final override {}
>  };
>
> struct C : public A {
>      void f() override {}
>  };
> void foo(B& b) { b.f(); }
> void bar(C& c) { c.f(); }
> ```
>
> ```
> C::f():
>         rep ret
> foo(B&):
>         rep ret
> bar(C&):
>         mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
>         mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
>         cmp     rax, OFFSET FLAT:C::f()
>         jne     .L6
>         rep ret
> .L6:
>         jmp     rax
> ```
>
> Why is this?

Here, compiler inlines call of `C::f` (`rep ret`) for the case when dynamic type of `c` is `C`:
then instead of calling `C::f`, it does what `C::f` does (-> nothing).

virtual call is still call for other dynamic type (`jmp     rax`).

Answer (score 0):

Optimisation wise, `final` only affects whether the compiler can prove what the derived type is at compile time. If the type is known then there is no need to help the compiler to know it.